# GZIP CSS completely breaks page

Tags: css, .htaccess, compression, gzip, zlib

Thanks for stopping by. I really tried this on my own, but once again it seems too much for me to handle.

### THE SITUATION...

---

I'm live with my own website on a shared hoster. When I came to the point of wanting to compress my tons of cms-generated js and css to make PageSpeedInsights and myself happy, I read into it and at last found out that **my hoster doesn't have neither mod_gzip nor mod_deflate installed**. What is installed is ZLIB. So I searched. Found the typical php append solution and didn't like it. Found a few neat lines of code for htaccess which made me happy cause they worked right away:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .php .js
php_flag output_buffering On
php_value output_handler ob_gzhandler
php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
```

I confirmed it's working by using [GIDZipTest](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php). This is all fine and I love it.
**But as soon as I put .css to the AddHandler List, my page completely breaks.**
I tried to use the [php solution with ob_gzhandler](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/compress-php-css-js-javascript-optimize-website-performance/) for only css files, but it ended up not working at all. Just does plain nothing.

### WORKAROUND? (NOT REALLY)

---

I manually minified all the css and uploaded a css.gz version of each file, serving it with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]
RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
```

This works fine as well.

### QUESTIONS!

---

1. What do I need to define/specifiy for css compression to work? I feel I'm just missing some conversion stuff...
2. When I'm serving my manually minified .css.gz files to a client, will they still be compressed extra?
3. Would this have any further advantages in filesize or should I rather just stick to the manually served versions and give a ** about Google PageSpeed?
   (GIDZipTest still shows «what if» scenarios even for the minified files, which are impressive numbers to be honest. I'd like that...)

Thank you in advance for any comment given.
Yours sincerely

Marian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you run into similar problems I advise to read [this article](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/compress-php-css-js-javascript-optimize-website-performance/) and get your [full web directory path](http://www.brmecham.com/how-to-find-the-absolute-path-on-your-web-server/) right!

Create a php script (for example: "gzip-css.php") with

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
header("content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>
```

and prepend it with .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
php_value auto_prepend_file "/full/path/to/that/file/see/link/above/gzip-css.php"
</FilesMatch>
```

to all .css files. This seemed to be the only solution for me until now. I would've got this right without asking here if I had found my full path earlier. Maybe someone still has a better idea on how to combine the AddHandler version with the css tho.

Things that did not work (completely disables all css):
- Adding .css to the AddHandler and **any** of the above (mine included) solutions.
- Serve manually gzipped css files and prepend a content type script
- Combination of the two

Answer (score 0):

PHP+zlib solution automatically compress EVERY PHP file served from webserver. This means that every file you put in your php handler will be sent compressed to the client browser. Anyway, the AddHandler directive tells the webserver to handle css files as php scripts, that's why I suppose they're "broken". Css files should have their own handler (text/css).

Another (not tested) solution could be keeping the handler you defined initially:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .php .js .css
```

and adding at the top of your css files this php code:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/css'); ?>
```

But I'm not sure this would work. This should tell browsers that they're actually receiving css files.

The best solution in these cases would be mod_deflate you mentioned.

Comment: Tried this. Created a file "gzip-css.php" with:`<?php 
header ("content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");?>` and then prepended the file using `<filesMatch "\.(css)$"> php_value auto_prepend_file gzip-css.php </filesMatch>` in the htaccess. Broke just in the same way. I'd love to just deflate, but **mod_deflate is not installed**. Or can I use deflate with zlib? If so, how? I already tried `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css` and nothing happened.

Comment: Well, I meant to create a .css extension file with that initial php code without any additional htaccess directive (look here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3942763.htm), and not a css file with .php extension, but maybe this solution won't work as well. I know that mod_deflate is not installed, then I'm afraid you don't have many choices.

Comment: Adding a content type header to the css files compressed with AddHandler oddly enough didn't work, although using ob_gzhandler from within the same script does. (See my own solution) Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You deliver the content as compressed but not just for transmission, which would be done with [*Content-Encoding*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.11). So the client does not decompress it before interpreting the content.

You can enable [*MultiViews*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) to allow automatic [content negotiation with *mod_negotiation*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html):

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
    Options MultiViews
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Just adding this to the .htaccess sadly didn't work either, though it looked quite promising. ;_; Tried it in various combinations of zlib and manual serving. Is there an order to be aware of?

Comment: @Marian No, this should work as is. Maybe you need to add `AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz`.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I found an .htaccess solution that worked for me without modifying any code.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .php .js .css
<Files *.css>
    Header set Content-type "text/css"
</Files>
php_flag zlib.output_compression On
php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```